# Linux - Automatically sending processes to background

Tags: linux

When I run commands (i.e. apt-get update), my server automatically sends the process to the background (as if I appended & to the command). Have any of you experienced this problem? I have searched around and can't find anything pertaining to this. This is on a Wheezy server.

The following is an example of a command output that gets automatically sent to the background:

```
debian-transmission@emachine-debian:~$ flexget --discover-now
2013-10-10 23:15 VERBOSE  discover      tv_shows        Discovering 38 titles ...
2013-10-10 23:15 INFO     discover      tv_shows        Ignoring interval because of --discover-now
2013-10-10 23:15 VERBOSE  est_series    tv_shows        The X Factor (US) S03E11 does not exist in tvrage database, assuming unreleased
2013-10-10 23:15 INFO     task          tv_shows        Plugin discover has requested task to be ran again after execution has completed.
2013-10-10 23:15 VERBOSE  est_series    tv_shows        The Walking Dead S03E17 does not exist in tvrage database, assuming unreleased
2013-10-10 23:15 VERBOSE  est_series    tv_shows        Supernatural S06E23 does not exist in tvrage database, assuming unreleased
2013-10-10 23:15 VERBOSE  est_series    tv_shows        Falling Skies S03E11 does not exist in tvrage database, assuming unreleased

[1]+  Stopped                 flexget --discover-now
```

Comment: Is your `flexget` an alias? Check it just in case with `alias flexget`. It can happen that you are using a wrapper that contains that `&`.

Comment: the same thing happens when running "apt-get", so it isn't flexget

Comment: Also, check http://flexget.com/wiki/Plugins/exec . On "Background options" it mentions the `allow_background` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your FlexGet and apt-get commands might be aliased, or you might have a shell script intercepting them.  Are any other commands starting in the background (what about ls, touch, mkdir, et al)?

- alias flexget, alias apt-get
- which flexget, which apt-get
- file `which flexget`, file `which apt-get`

Looking at FlexGet (http://flexget.com/wiki/Plugins/exec), it suggests the Allow background option, but says that you (may) need the 'start' command.

- Allow background option

*Normally, FlexGet will wait the given command to finish so it can capture the return status and log the output. But if the command takes a long time to run (ex. direct downloads of large files), it will prevent further processing until the command completes. To fork the command into a background process so that FlexGet continues processing without delay, you not only have to add an ampersand (&) at the end of the command, you have to use the {{allow_background}} option. Note, this option will also prevent FlexGet from determining if the command failed, so it will not retry.*

- You may need the start command

*If you experience problems backgrounding your task, try using the "start" command. In the above example, setting "allow_background: yes" and appending the & still wouldn't background the process.*

Comment: Tried the above, however, no aliases are set besides ls colors.

Comment: Are some commands placed into the background, or ALL commands?

Comment: what is result of 'stty -a' command? The behavior resembles strange behavior from stty setting errors.  Try "stty sane" and see what happens.